# How do i set the powershell script to treat the GPO name as a variable

Tags: powershell

I am running the below command manually one by one:

```
copy-gpo -sourcename "each-gpo-name" -sourcedomain "ES.contoso.local" -targetname "ES - orig gpo name" -targetdomain "UK.contoso.com"
```

I want to copy hundreds of GPOs from the ES forest/domain to the UK forest/domain and add a prefix to the GPO of the country eg "ES - ...."

From what i can find on the internet i would need to set the GPOs into an Array

```
$GPOARRAY = get-gpo -all -domain "ES.contoso.local"
```

and then set the `-sourcename` and the suffix of the `-targetname` as the array variable?

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use a `foreach` loop and in that loop you can do your "add prefix" operation for all. You can store the result in an arraylist in this case and not an array because that will make more sense here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could something like the below help you?

```
$sourceDomain = "ES.Contoso.Local"
$targetDomain = "UK.contoso.com"

$GPOArray = Get-GPO -All -Domain $sourceDomain
foreach ($GPO in $GPOArray){
    $GPOName = $GPO.DisplayName
    Copy-GPO -SourceName $GPOName -SourceDomain $sourceDomain -TargetName "ES - $GPOName" -TargetDomain $targetDomain
}
```

Be careful if you use this, hopefully, it at least points you in the right direction :)

Comment: I just needed to change that last command -sourcename $gpo to $gponame works a treat

Comment: I would give a up vote but im under 15 rep :( but give the tick